# VBA change date text to date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have an exported excel with date formated this way `24.12.2019` , how can i use VBA and set a macro so that when i click on macro it becomes `2019-12-24`. I tried to find in stackoverflow for related post, but to unavail. Both are general text format and i want to keep it that way.

Comment: Would your dates always have the format "dd.mm.yyyy" or can it be "dd.m.yyyy"?

Comment: @JvdV the date is always "dd.mm.yyyy" format when i export the information, so i'd like a solution to make the format "yyyy-mm-dd" to make my life easier.

Comment: And you definately want to retain the text format?

Comment: it doesnt necessary need to be in text format i guess, date format works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's codename
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Change "A" to whichever column data is in
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr) 'Change accordingly again
    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
    rng.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, I did not read the comments above. Then it's strange why he wrote that he want to keep it as text. I'd be better to change the post then.

Comment: "No data was selected to parse" error on line "rng.TextToColumns ...."

Comment: @JiaHaoWang, You'll have to be specific which `Sheet`, which `Column` and which `Range` as explained in my post. The code works on my end.

Comment: Yes, JvDV's code works for me as well. As said, you'll get dates as output

Comment: Can u kindly tell me what does "rng.TextToColumns...." line does? im abit confused.

Comment: @JiaHaoWang, it does the same thing as the build-in function Text To columns, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) you can read about it more detailed. Basically we told this function we currently have a range of values in the `xlDMYFormat` and we want to return it's datevalue into the same range. Therefor ending up with a range of actual date values which we can then format to  "YYYY-MM-DD"`

Answer (score 2):

As you want to keep everything as text have a look at the following code and try to adjust it to your sheet.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1:A4")

    Dim sngCell As Range
    For Each sngCell In rg
        ' This will set the format of the cell to text
        sngCell.NumberFormat = "@"

        ' This will change the format of the date
        ' Be careful there is a lot of internal casting going on
        sngCell.Value = Format(sngCell.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    Next

End Sub
```

And you could use this function to get the result as text

```
Function dtTxt(inpdte As String) As String
    dtTxt = Format(inpdte, "YYYY-MM-DD")
End Function
```

Comment: If you go with a loop, definately store values in memory (array), format `rg` in one go. Otherwise, this should work =)

Comment: Yes, right, but might be too much for the OP, otherwise [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array) is a good explanation

Comment: @JiaHaoWang, you should close your question by picking an answer and mark it as such (click checkmark to the right of the answer you feel suited)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateText = "24.12.2019"
DateArr = Split(DateText, ".")
MsgBox DateArr(2) & "-" & DateArr(1) & "-" & DateArr(0)
```

If you want the output as date value:

```
DateValue(DateArr(2) & "-" & DateArr(1) & "-" & DateArr(0))
```