# How can I work with excel date after exporting a file from a site

Tags: excel, date

I've exported an excel file that have some column whit date in it.
when I want to work whit that column's cells(for example different between two date) excel shows me an error. but when I double click on a cell, it work properly.
you can see below that first two cells have correct value after I double clicked on them. But next three cells still don't work properly.
I will be thankful if anyone helps me.

***Cells example***

[image]

Comment: When you are exporting to excel then it is storing dates as text and when you double click and exit cell then excel converting cell contents to true date. So, you need `DATEVALUE()` function to convert this text into date.

Comment: actually I've changed type of cell to date after exporting.excel shows that the cell type is "date". but again have the problem.

Comment: Changing only format will not convert text to date because cell format only changes format not values. So, you need to convert these text to date either by formula or by VBA macro or one by one double clicking on each cells.

Comment: yes.thank you very much.may I ask you help me with VBA macro? because i don't know what code should i use.

Comment: What dates are those supposed to be?  Valid dates in Excel must be in the range `1-Jan-1900` to `31-Dec-9999`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Harun24HR's comment, you could think of a macro to deal with the situation (if the situation repeats itself over and over -> would something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.doubleclick) be working?
`Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate  Application.DoubleClick`)

or manually add a neighbour column with formula in the cell such as =DATEVALUE(ThatNeighbourCell)

Also the formatting style of the cell might be relevant.

Comment: thank you.i think it will work.may i ask you help me to write a macro that double click on cell A1 to A400 for example.

Answer (score 0):

macro is such as this:

```
Sub doubleClickIt()

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Select 'adapt name
  Range("A1:A400").Activate
  Application.doubleClick

End Sub
```

But I'm not sure it will do the trick, double clicking as a user seems to trigger different results than double clicking from the macro..
Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655422/vba-change-date-text-to-date-format) which seems very relevant to your issue, if you intend to go for a macro.